# How do I use the Rally attributecombobox (SDK 2) to show allowed values for Portfolio items?

Tags: rally

I need to show the list of allowed values for the State field by Type for Portfolio items. The following code returns URL's instead of values? What am I doing wrong?

```
var typeCombobox= Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
             items: [{
                 xtype: 'rallyattributecombobox',
                 model: 'PortfolioItem/FEATURE',
                 field: 'State',
                 multiSelect: true,                                          
            }],         
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The State attribute on Portfolio Items is an Object. Ideally the following syntax:

`field: 'State.Name'`

Would be workable - and the constructor would be smart enough to traverse down to the Name field on the Object. I've filed a Defect on this issue on this with Rally Engineering.

The best workaround in the meantime would probably be to use the [Ext.form.field.ComboBox](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox) and populate the drop down values via a query for valid PI States. Thanks for bringing this to our attention!

Comment: Mark, thank you for your prompt answer! I tried your suggestion but get the following error: Uncaught Rally.ui.combobox.AttributeComboBox._populateStore(): field config must be specified when creating a Rally.ui.combobox.AttributeComboBox. 
I have tried so many options and still can't find the problem. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Good catch! It should be able to traverse to the Name property of the State Object. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I am glad it is not just my lack of understanding! I will try using your combobox method on Fri when I am back at work!

Comment: I have the combobox working with the State datastore, however I can't work out which field to use to filer the states for a Portfolio item type. Please help?